# How to upload files to cloudinary from shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, cloudinary

I am trying write a shell script to upload a file encoded in `base64` to cloudinary using cURL like this

```
#!/bin/bash

timestamp=$(date +%s)

apiSecret=$2

fileName=$1

data="api_key=679764637516936&file=$(base64 -w 0 $fileName)&timestamp=${timestamp}"

datatobehashed="timestamp=${timestamp}$apiSecret"

hash=$(echo ${datatobehashed} | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}')

curl -v "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/zolatech/raw/upload --data \"${data}&signature=${hash}\""

echo ""
```

but it returns `400 Bad Request` with the following response `{"error":{"message":"Invalid Signature 55683272b2d893c0d140af596a01d23977ede889. String to sign - 'timestamp=1484757367'."}}`

so **am i not using the API correctly?** or **is there something wrong with my code?**

Comment: Run your script using the option `-x` to check the values of the variables.

Comment: all variables have the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is not echoed correctly, which causes the expected `sha1` to mismatch:

```
hash=$(echo -n ${datatobehashed} | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

You should use `echo -n`, otherwise you'll end up with a trailing newline character and bad hash.

**echo** -n

> -n    Do not print the trailing newline character.

↳ [GNU Bash : echo invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html)